# How to use external real-trace mobility model in ONE simulator?

Tags: dtn, one-simulator

I am trying to run a simulation in ONE simulator using the haggle-one-infocom2006-complete model from CRAWDAD, but I'm getting an error saying:

Can't start: error in configuration file(s)
Invalid offset line '1  CONN    16      12      up'

Here is how I specified it in the settings:

Group.movementModel = ExternalMovement
ExternalMovement.file = haggle-one-infocom2006-complete.txt

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The first line of the input file should contain offset information:

`minTime maxTime minX maxX minY maxY minZ maxZ`

See the [ExternalMovementReader](https://github.com/akeranen/the-one/blob/master/src/input/ExternalMovementReader.java#L22) class for details.